# jQuery function not working inside jinja2 block

Tags: javascript, jquery, jinja2

I am building a multipage Flask web app with a layout.html parent template and several child templates. One of the child templates contains a form to fill out. One of the boxes of the form ("tags") should autocomplete with suggestions as you type. I will first start by giving an example of what I know DOES work:

This is test.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

It works as intended (for a functioning demo, see: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). Note that it is a standalone html file and has no parent. Now I try the following:

Here is the parent template, layout.html (edited for conciseness):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}HBL{% endblock %}</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic|Source+Code+Pro:500">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/site.css"/>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  

    {% block head %}{% endblock %}
</head>



<body style="background-color: white">

  
    {% block main_content %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the child template with the form, form.html:

```
{% extends "shared/_layout.html" %}
{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}

{% block head %}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>
{% endblock %}

{% block main_content %}

    <div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

The autocomplete function does not work. When I type something into the box, I am not provided with autocomplete suggestions (i.e., I am simply typing into a box as if the jQuery was not there at all), unlike with the test.html example above. HOWEVER, if I place the tags widget into layout.html (parent template) it works. Here is the relative location of the widget in layout.html:

```
...
<body style="background-color: white">
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
...
```

Putting this altogether my theory is that something wrong happens when I put the widget inside the jinja "main_content" block, but I am new to jQuery and cannot figure out why. Also note that I achieve the same results I've listed above when I move the  stuff from form.html to layout.html (while keeping everything else the same).

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: do you get any error in console, try putting in your debug messages in console to find out what is happening with code

Answer (score 0):

A friend has helped me fix the issue. I will edit this answer with the fix shortly once I take a look at his commit history.